Retrieve distinct values from two columns in a single table in Tableau Desktop
I have two different columns in the same table that contain data, and I need the unique values obtained by combining both columns.

In this scenario, all team names are split between the two columns. I need to combine these two columns into one, ensuring that the resulting column contains only distinct values from both.
In the 'Away Teams' section, there are four countries—El Salvador, Indonesia, Israel, and Kuwait—that are not found in the 'Home Team' column. To calculate the winning count for each team, how can we incorporate these teams into the list?

What is your expected output, something like "Argentina Chile" or the sum of say a score for [Home Team] + [Away Team]
Also the second part of this questions seems to be a different ask than what is stated in your question title.

The expected output will be a single column containing all country names, sourced from either the Home Team or the Away Team.


Select both fields in the data pane in the left margin.
Right click  to get a context menu.
Choose Create Combined Field
Edit the combined field if you want to choose a different delimiter

